# pyautogui остановка треков или же пауза

Tags: python, pyautogui

Можно ли с помощью pyautogui остановить или поставить на паузу трек? я пытался найти но негде не нашел, я только знаю как переключить трек, при попытке поставить трек на паузу pause() то ничего не происходит

Comment: Вроде бы можно, если кнопка паузы всегда стоит на одном месте. https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html#mouse-clicks.

Comment: это не то что мне нужно, мне нужно чтобы это выполнялось в фоне, но предпологаю что это сделать не получится...(